# mysql multidatabase change at once

Tags: mysql, database, replication

I'm looking for solution for scenario:
 1. One Web application  (on Symfony)
 2. One client = one database (mysql)
 3. If I change something in database structure for ex.: add new table or add column - this must change on every database (for all clients)

I have problem in point 3. I'm looking for ready solutions or tips how to build it.
In this scenario I specially skip: replication, load balancing, mysql fabrick, cluster mysql, cloud solutions).

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: my client need configuration what is in description for his projedct

Comment: you can make a centeralized database (server hosting) and integrate the host adress in your code (requires network connection to work on the clients side)

Answer (score 0):

I founded flyway and liquibase. I would test this software solution. Thanks all.